manipulation in reputation numbers?
I am really concerned about my reputation going up and down lately - there seems to be something wrong: I was nearing 2.000, now I am back at 1.600. It is going up and down by 200 points daily, so somebody must be messing around with it.
I am member of several area51 sites but I have never encountered something like that before.
Do you have similar experiences - Thank you!

I'm going to bet that it is the "suspicious vote" doohickey which is off its meds again. 

not necessarily off its meds; there might be users who are "helpfully" trying to upvote one user over and over.

I had this a couple days ago too. It looked like someone had upvoted everything I had ever posted. Then a day later, all of those votes were gone. (Specifically, I had received one vote per answer, all within the same hour. These upvotes then disappeared the next day.)
I can query for suspicious voting behaviour as a moderator, but nothing comes up; the system doesn't detect any abnormal activity.
I don't know how to proceed with this one so I just let it go for now. On the other hand, if someone had been summarily downvoting me, then I'd get out the pitchforks and torches.
